# Limit typeahead results

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I'm using the angular-ui typeahead directive to connect to the Google Maps API and retrieve an array of addresses. Normally when I need to limit the amount of results visible I do something like:

```
<input typeahead="eye for eye in array | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:10">
```

That works perfectly and the results are limited to 10. However, when I try to do the same thing with asynchronous results, it doesn't work. It will give more results than I specified in the `limitTo`.

Am I doing something incorrectly below?

[Here is a plunker:](http://plnkr.co/edit/lwhA9sWNSGrMHhkndy7b?p=preview)

HTML:

```
  <input ng-model="asyncSelected" typeahead="address for address in getLocation($viewValue) | limitTo:1" typeahead-loading="loadingLocations">
```

JavaScript:

```
  $scope.getLocation = function(val) {
    return $http.get('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json', {
      params: {
        address: val
      }
    }).then(function(res){
      var addresses = [];
      angular.forEach(res.data.results, function(item){
        addresses.push(item.formatted_address);
      });
      return addresses;
    });
  };
```

Currently i'm doing the following to workaround, i'm just curious why a simple `limitTo` doesn't work.

```
$scope.getLocation = function(val) {
    return $http.get('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json', {
      params: {
        address: val
      }
    }).then(function(res){
      var addresses = [];
      var resultNumber = res.data.results.length > 5 ? 5 : res.data.results.length;
      for(var i = 0; i < resultNumber; i++){
        var obj = res.data.results[i];
        var addr = obj.formatted_address;
        addresses.push(addr);
      }
            return addresses;
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

typeahead doesn't seem to support promises. So it's better to just bind it to a collection, and then update that collection when you get a response from google. You might want to think about debouncing tough, now a request is done for every letter typed.

Note that you also don't need the filter anymore, because the filter is already being done by google sever side.

http://plnkr.co/edit/agwEDjZvbq7ixS8El3mu?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('app',['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope','$http', function($scope,$http){
  $scope.locations = [];
  $scope.$watch('asyncSelected', function(val) {
    $http.get('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json', {
      params: {
        address: val
      }
    }).then(function(res){
      $scope.locations.length = 0;
      angular.forEach(res.data.results, function(item){
        $scope.locations.push(item.formatted_address);
      });
    });
  });

}]);
```

```
  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@~3.1.1" data-semver="3.2.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="ui-bootstrap@*" data-semver="0.11.0" src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.1" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.1.1" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="asyncSelected" placeholder="Address" typeahead="address for address in locations | limitTo:1" typeahead-loading="loadingLocations" class="form-control">
  </body>

</html>
```