# Angularjs typeahead http and typeahead filters not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have ant typeahead that gets data from http, but I need to use custom filters too, like 'limitTo:2' or comparing with another variables etc, but it's not working.

When you get data from http it's not possible to use other filters?
I have a Plunker example that I made limitTo:2 and it shows all results.
If you insert 'a' it don't show only two results.

[example plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HNJ8jc056e1G48Xzd6LB?p=preview)

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="asyncSelected" placeholder="Locations loaded via $http" typeahead="address for address in getLocation($viewValue) | limitTo:2" typeahead-loading="loadingLocations" class="form-control">
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Limit typeahead results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25041613/limit-typeahead-results)